# SVG artwork for XY axis plotter

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I'm having an issue with my XY axis plotter.

Does anyone know what minimum line weight I should use? The lines on my SVG files keep doubling up.

Also, how do I 'fill'? Do I have to draw a series of hatches?

Best, Alex

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is actually a problem related to your plotters control software and not graphic design.

Comment: WOW, I've not seen one of these for about 15 years, even then it was 10 years out of date!

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft, I'm recreating handwriting so an XY axis plotter is kind of needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your plotter will read the vector file as a series of lines of undimensioned width. You can use any line width that will accurately represent your objective. If you have a line that does not create a closed shape (circle, box, triangle, curves that "hold water"), it will be the width of the tool selected by your plotter.

Depending on your device, closed shapes will either be outlined or automatically filled. The software which interfaces the image to the machine is the best place to check regarding fills.

Laser cutters set to cut will convert closed shapes into "drop-outs" that fall free of the item being cut. When the cutter is set to scan (engrave), those shapes become filled automatically, with specific parameters provided within the software.

If your lines are doubling up, consider to set your line width to hairline, but double-check the result on your plotter with a test run or two.

Comment: Doubling can also be caused buy actually having 2 lines on top of eachother.

Comment: Hello @fred_dot_u. I'm using 0.2pt line weight, which is very much a hairline and it's still coming out doubled up (both sides of the line).

Comment: @joojaa - they're definitely stacked, there's only one line there and it's being drawn twice.

Comment: @Alex then cosult your dirvers manual. For example for  epilog lasers  do not considered  0.2 pt a hairline it has to be atleast 0.072 pt or  0.001 inches or less to be considered a hairline. SO i suspect 0.2 is not yet thin enough despite what you think.